# In Interface Builder, is it possible to reuse an IBOutlet button property?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have a set of 20 identical buttons that are all linked to the same action. The only thing different is their tags. However I found it's not possible to link them all to the same IBOutlet @property. Do I really have to create 20 IBOutlet @properties for each of these 20 identical buttons?

Otherwise I get the `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btn_chooseMark.` error and the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need any outlets at all. Put all 20 in the view with individual tags. When you need to access one, use

```
UIButton *button = [self.view viewWithTag:x];
```

You obviously can put this in a 'for' loop. Also, using one action item for all 20 is perfectly normal and a usual ObjectiveC practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to manipulate the buttons outside of the IBAction, create an IBOutletCollection, like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *myButtons;
```

You can access the buttons like so:

```
for (UIButton *button in myButtons){
        if (button.tag == 2) {
               [button setAlpha:1];
        }
}
```

And do what you want to them.  Otherwise, if you want to manipulate them inside the IBAction, change the sender from "id" to "UIButton *".  (You probably already knew that, but hey, why not be thorough?)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want an [IBOutletConnection](http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/). Connecting all the buttons to the same single outlet wouldn't make sense. Each object is supposed to it's own pointer, and the relationship UI Object-pointer is one-to-one.